# Are there any way to use FOSUserbundle register system in my own form?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I made it, I register the user and when I confirm the user the app makes login automatically.

If I close the session, I can't open a new session with that new user from my custom register form, I got a flag of "bad credentials", but with same login form I can login perfectly with users registered with the FOSUserbundle register form. Both forms have the same code.

```
<form id="login-form" name="login-form" class="nobottommargin" action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

    <label for="login-form-username">Correo Electrónico:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control" required="required" />

    <label for="login-form-password">Contraseña:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" value="" class="form-control" />

    <button class="button" id="login-form-submit" name="login-form-submit" value="login">Acceder</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To indent your code use 4 spaces. It makes the code way more readable. For [formatting options check](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: are you talking about registration or login? because i look at the form it seems a login form and you talk about registration so i am confused

Comment: Have you checked that your registration form is creating them correctly? You normally have to manually encode the password.

Comment: check the password field if it's plainpassword or just password, that should be plainpassword

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'm using in the controller for create and update the info of the user:

```
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$userUtils = $this->container->get('fos_user.util.token_generator');

$user = $userManager->createUser();

$user->setNombre($nombre);
$user->setEmail($email);
$user->setUsername($email);
$user->setPlainPassword($pass);
$user->setEnabled(true);
$user->setConfirmationToken($userUtils->generateToken());
$user->addRole('ROLE_USER');

$this->mailer->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);

$em->persist($user);

$em->flush();
```